# Your car only turns right!

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, path-finding, decision-problem

#### Introduction

You have the misfortune of being stuck in a runaway car on an obstacle course.  All of the car's features are non-responsive, save for the steering system, which is damaged.  It can drive straight, or it can turn right.  Can the car be guided to safety?

#### Mechanics

Your car begins in the upper-left corner of an 8x8 map, and is trying to get to safety in the lower-right corner.  The car has an orientation (initially to the right), measured in 90-degree increments.  The car can perform one of two actions:

1. Drive one square forward, or
2. Turn 90 degrees clockwise, then drive one square forward

Note that the car is unable to turn sharply enough to perform a 180-degree turn on a single square.

Some of the squares are obstacles.  If the car enters an obstacle square, it crashes.  Everything outside the 8x8 course is assumed to be obstacles, so driving off the course is equivalent to crashing.

The lower-right square is the safe square, which allows the car to escape the obstacle course.  The starting square and safe square are assumed not to be obstacles.

#### Task

You must write a program or function which takes as its input an 8x8 array (matrix, list of lists, etc.), representing the obstacle course.  The program returns or prints a Boolean, or something similarly truthy.  If it's possible for the car to make it to the safe square without crashing (i.e., if the map is solvable), the output is `True`, otherwise, it's `False`.

#### Scoring

Standard code golf rules - the winner is the code with the fewest bytes.

Bonuses:

- If, for a solvable map, your code outputs a valid series of driver inputs which guide the car to the safe square, deduct 10 percentage points from your score.  An example output format might be `SRSSR` (indicating Straight, Right, Straight, Straight, Right).  This output would replace the standard `True` output.
- If, for an unsolvable map, your code's output distinguishes between situations where a crash is unavoidable, and situations where it's possible to drive around the obstacle course forever, deduct 10 percentage points from your score.  An example output might be `Crash` if a crash is unavoidable, or `Stuck` if the car is stuck in the obstacle course forever.  These outputs would replace the standard `False` output for an unsolvable map.

#### Example

If the program is given an 8x8 array such as this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

It would be interpreted as a map like this, with black squares indicating obstacles:

[image]

And a possible solution might be:

[image]

Since a solution exists, the program should return/print `True` for this map.  The sequence of moves shown here is `SSSSRSRRRSRSSRRRSSRSSS`.

Comment: Could you also provide example inputs for for the `Crash` and `Stuck` cases?

Comment: I wrote some *incredibly* simple test cases for `Crash` and `Stuck`. They're [here](http://ix.io/eBH) because of how long they are. Row 2 filled, everything else empty -> `Crash`. Row 7 filled, everything else empty -> `Stuck`

Comment: I'm confused about percentage *points* (as opposed to percentages). Getting either bonus multiplies your score by 0.9. Does getting both multiply it by 0.8 or 0.9^2?

Comment: Another question: Can we exit with an exception or do we have to go out gracefully?

Comment: I was attempting to imply that the percentage points are deducted from the actual number of code bytes, so claiming both bonuses results in multiplication by 0.8.  Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Exiting with an exception is OK, as long as that exception alerts the viewer about the (non)existence of a solution.  No ambiguity allowed, basically.

Comment: For Stuck or Crash, could we return something like 'S' or 'C'? Or does it have to be the whole word? This doesn't _seem_ ambiguous to me.

Comment: Sure, S and C are fine.  My outputs were only suggestions.

Comment: "Two wrongs don't make a right, but three lefts do." - Dad.

Comment: I actually considered using 'three lefts' in the title.

Comment: "Your car can make only zero or three lefts!"

Comment: @feersum "Your car is pretty shitty!"

Comment: @flawr But it's very fast and that's what's important!

Comment: Is it ok if the function takes a named argument as the board, instead of just the argument? i.e. `f(b=board)`?

Comment: Sure, the input formats is not particularly important.

Comment: This question reminded me of an odd route I took to a previous work site. The route that I took was literally exactly 7 lefts from home to work, and vice versa (7 rights from work to home). No joke. I took that route for a while before I realized it.

Comment: That's a funny story.  Hopefully the route didn't cross over itself!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6) - 122 <strike>124</strike> <strike>148 <strike>162</strike> <strike>172</strike> <strike>178</strike> <strike>187</strike> <strike>190</strike> <strike>193</strike> 208</strike> bytes

Many thanks to Optimizer and DocMax for helpful suggestions on how to improve this code:

```
F=a=>(D=(x,y,d)=>!D[i=[x,y,d]]&&(D[i]=1,x-=~d%2,y-=~-~d%2,x*y==49||!((x|y)&8||a[y][x])&&(D(x,y,d)||D(x,y,~-d%4))),D(-1,0))
```

Returns `true` (truthy) for solvable and `false` (falsy) for unsolvable.

Works only in Firefox as of today becasue of JavaScript 1.7 features.

[**Test Board**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5h4jrdm/3/)

Comment: This is 193 bytes : `D=(x,y,d,t,a)=>!t[i=x+y*8+d*64]&&(t[i]=1,x+=d==0?1:d==2?-1:0,y+=d==1?1:d==3?-1:0,x==7&&y==7||!((x|y)&~7||a[y][x])&&G(x,y,d,t,a));G=(x,y,d,t,a)=>D(x,y,d,t,a)||D(x,y,d+1&3,t,a);F=a=>G(0,0,0,[],a)` .

Comment: @Optimizer: thank you, I updated my answer.

Comment: 172 : `D=d=>!t[i=x+y*8+d/4]&&(t[i]=1,x+=d?d^2?0:-1:1,y+=d^1?d^3?0:-1:1,x==7&&y==7||!((x|y)&~7||b[y][x])&&G(x,y,d));G=(X,Y,d)=>D(d,x=X,y=Y)||D(d+1&3,x=X,y=Y);F=a=>G(0,0,0,b=a,t={})` - Tested.

Comment: @Optimizer I'm still getting true for the second test case `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`. That should give false.

Comment: That is because since `x` and `y` are both globals, you cannot run two testcases before reloading the page...

Comment: @Optimizer sorry, your're perfectly right. I was running some test cases with globals like `a`, `b`, `c`, and that would break the code. Feeling ashame now. Thank so much, you're the best!

Comment: Is there a bitwise and operator in Javascript? I think you can do `x&y==7` instead of `x==7&&y==7`.

Comment: You can save a total of 9 more by replacing `x+=d?d^2?0:-1:1` with `x+=d&1?0:1-d` and `y+=d^1?d^3?0:-1:1` with `y+=d&1&&2-d`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman well, those are not the same, but thanks, I optimized that part in a different way now :)

Comment: @DocMax thanks! I implemented your suggestions in my new version.

Comment: Two more things which I think may help (but I'm not entirely sure): Instead of `D=d=>` and calling `D` with `D(...,x=X,y=Y)` it saves two to do `D=>(d,x,y)` and call it `D(...,X,Y)`. I just don't know if there are side effects.   The other is to replace `x+[y]==77` with `x*y==49` (yay primes) since I don't think (49,1) or (1,49) are possible.

Comment: @DocMax Awesome, thanks! I also replaced the input array with `D`, any object. Together a few other optimizations I've done, we're at 148 bytes now!!! Wish I could share my points with you guys :)

Comment: I really, _really_ like how you've abused `D` as both the function and the object.

Comment: One more for the morning: save one more by replacing my `d&1?0:1-d` with `d-3&&1-d`.

Comment: Replace `G` with its definition. Then start at x=-1: `F=a=>(D=(x,y,d)=>!D[i=[x,y,d]]&&(D[i]=1,x+=d-3&&1-d,y+=d&1&&2-d,x*y==49||!((x|y)&8||a[y][x])&&(D(x,y,d)||D(x,y,d+1&3))),D(-1,0,0))`. And now it fits well inside a tweet at 128 chars.

Comment: Thanks so much @DocMax that's really a great job! - I managed to save 4 more bytes switching the direction sign (right = 0, down = -1 ...). Down to 124 bytes now B-)

Comment: @RenaeLider Are you sure? I tested it and seems ok to me. Your board has no solution.

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2 - 123 <s>125 133 146 148 150 154 160</s>

`True` on success, `False` on failure.

```py
def f(h=1,v=0,b=0,x=0,y=0,c=[]):s=x,y,h,v;a=b,x+h,y+v,c+[s];return(s in c)==(x|y)&8==b[y][x]<(x&y>6or f(h,v,*a)|f(-v,h,*a))
```

You must supply input like `f(b=var_containing_board)`.

#### Lambda version - 154

Returns `0` (falsy) for failure, `True` for success.

```
F=lambda b,x=0,y=0,h=1,v=0,c=[]:0if[x,y,h,v]in c or x|y>7or x|y<0 or b[y][x]else x&y==7or F(b,x+h,y+v,h,v,c+[[x,y,h,v]])or F(b,x+h,y+v,-v,h,c+[[x,y,h,v]])
```

Thanks to Will and Brandon for making the function shorter than the lambda. Also for adding more horizontal scrolling :D

Thanks to xnor for superior bit-bashing and logic!

Edit note: I am reasonably confident that `b[y][x]` will never be executed when going out of range. Since we are outside of the board, the history check `s in c` will be `False`. Then the boundary check `(x|y)&8` will be `8`. Then python will not even check the last value of `==` because the first two are already different.

Comment: The functional version can combine the two ifs which both return; as return alone returns None which is falsy, you also don't need to return 0. .just returning the favour ;)

Comment: If you flip the checks you can combine both ifs too

Comment: Can you combine both return statements?

Comment: Python seems to be winning so far!

Comment: instead of `not(...)` you can do `(...)-1` :)  And there's a few spaces you can zap between numbers and keywords.

Comment: @Will Thanks, I knew there was a better way to do that :D Um, I couldn't find any spaces to remove that don't cause me syntax error. I don't really get why `x|y>7or` works but `x|y<0or` doesn't...

Comment: You can make an octal literal beginning with `0o`.

Comment: It gives the wrong answer if you try `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]` as the fourth array (as in the OP's example).

Comment: @RenaeLider I believe it correctly gets false in that case. I don't see how the car could make it to the end. Could you give me some more info?

Comment: You can shorten `x|y>7or x|y<0` to `(x|y)&-8`.

Comment: The `(x|y)&-8` trick doesn't play well with the `(...)-1` for `not`, but it's still worth it if you revert to `not(...)`. And I think `return((s in c)==b[y][x]==0<x|y<8)` is even shorter (though I haven't checked that it works)`.

Comment: @xnor Thanks for the tips! I had been trying to golf down those statements for quite a while, but I never could get it to be worth losing the `-1` for `not`. I'm going to fiddle with the `==` thing to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think I see why it doesn't work. First, it should be `0<=x|y<8`. Also, `b[y][x]` must not be evaluated with out-of-bounds indices, so it needs to be short-circuited with something like `0<=x|y<8and ...`.

Comment: @xnor I think I got it to work with `(x|y)&-8`. I just had to change the order of the `==` so that it would short-circuit itself (I didn't know python did this until just today). You saved me almost enough to get back into the lead :D

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That's clever. I had no idea that chained comparison operators short circuit.

Answer (score 9):

## C (GNU-C), 163 bytes * 0.9 = 146.7

<strike>#C (GNU-C), 186 bytes * 0.9 = 167.4</strike>

My new version uses a signed rather than unsigned integer. Earlier I was afraid of signed right shift, but I realized since the sign bit is the goal square, it doesn't matter what happens after that.

The function takes an array of bits (ones represent blocked squares) in the form of a 64-bit integer. The bits are arranged least to most significant in the same way you would read a book. It returns -1 for a crash, 0 for driving forever, or 1 for escaping to the bottom right corner.

```
g(long long o) {
    typeof(o) a=0,i=255,r=1,u=0,l=0,d=0,M=~0LLU/i,D;
    for( ;i--;d = D<<8&~o)
        a |= D = d|r,
        r = (r|u)*2&~M&~o,
        u = (u|l)>>8&~o,
        l = ((l|d)&~M)/2&~o;
    return a<0?:-!(d|r|u|l);
}
```

**Test program**

```
f(long long o){typeof(o)a=0,i=255,r=1,u=0,l=0,d=0,M=~0LLU/i,D;for(;i--;d=D<<8&~o)a|=D=d|r,r=(r|u)*2&~M&~o,u=(u|l)>>8&~o,l=((l|d)&~M)/2&~o;return a<0?:-!(d|r|u|l);}
{
    char* s[] = {"Crash", "Stuck", "Escape"};
    #define P(x) puts(s[f(x)+1])
    L ex = 0x4640500C0A034020;
    P(ex);
    L blocked = 0x4040404040404040;
    P(blocked);

    L dead = 0x10002;
    P(dead);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Escape
Stuck
Crash
```

Python array-to-hex converter:

```
a2b=lambda(A):"0x%X"%sum(A[i/8][i%8]<<i for i in range(64))
```

Comment: Replace `memset(&M,~1,8)` (15 chars) with `M=~(-1ULL/255)` (14 chars).

Comment: @R.. Nice one! -4 bytes from that.

Comment: I like the input format - very cool!

Comment: I'm getting 'crash' for `P(0x00fefefefefefefe);` =( Should be straight shot to upper right, one turn, straight to corner. Same for `P(0x00eeeeeeeeeeeeee);` (dead end on 4th col). I don't think you need to assign `a` initially.

Comment: @tolos You've got the row/column-major order transposed. To have the top row and right column open, it should be `0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f00`. Also it is necessary to initialize `a` because later it is only modified by ORing in additional bits, so I can't afford to have an unwanted bit set initially.

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 187 <s>213</s>

### 207 chars, 10% bonus for printing path

```python
b=map(ord," "*9+" ".join("".join("o "[i]for i in j)for j in input())+" "*9)
def r(p,d,s):
 p+=(1,9,-1,-9)[d]
 if b[p]&1<<d:b[p]^=1<<d;return(s+"S")*(p==79)or r(p,d,s+"S")or r(p,(d+1)%4,s+"R")
print r(8,0,"")
```

On the test input it finds a slightly different path: `SSSSRSRSRRSSRSSRRSRSSRSSSSS`

The general approach is to first turn the input into a spaces and `o`s.  Spaces have a hex of `20`, so all four lower bits are unset.  `o` has a hex of `6F`, so the low four bits are all set.

A border of `o`s is placed around the board so we don't have to worry about bad indices.

As we walk over the board, we use the bits in each tile to see if we are allowed to pass when coming from that side.  In this way, we avoid infinite loops.  Its not enough to have a single boolean per tile, as your exit direction depends on your entry direction, so tiles can be visited twice.

We then do a recursive search for a safe path.

Comment: "Your car begins in the upper-left corner of an 8x8 map" - can't you hardcode `9` in place of `w=len(b[0])+1`, etc?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thank you, how could I have overlooked that? :D

Comment: You can reverse your ternary statement and replace `p==79` with `p-79`. I got a syntax error doing this both ways without a space before the `else`. I think that trick only works with `if`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think the depth test has to before the recurse?  I've been playing with a multiplication by boolean instead.

Comment: I just found a really neat trick. You probably know that `-~x` == `x+1` but both unary operators have higher precedence than multiplication, division and modulus! So `(d+1)%4` could be `-~d%4`! This also would work with `x-1` but just use `~-x` instead.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript - <s>270 - 20% = 216</s> 262 - 20% = 210 bytes

Since there ought to be at least one solution that earns both bonuses (and doesn't lead to a ridiculous stack depth ;)...

Minified:

```
V=I=>{n=[N=[0,0,0]];v={};v[N]='';O='C';for(S='';n[0];){m=[];n.map(h=>{[x,y,d]=h;D=i=>[1,0,-1,0][d+i&3];p=v[h];for(j=2;j--;){O=v[c=[X=x+D(j),Y=y+D(3-3*j)),d+j&3]]?'K':O;J=X|Y;J<0||J>7||I[Y][X]||v[c]?O:(m.push(c),v[c]=p+'SR'[j])}S=(x&y)>6?p:S});n=m;}return S||O;};
```

Expanded:

```
V = I => {
    n = [N=[0,0,0]];
    v = {};
    v[N] = '';
    O = 'C';

    for( S = ''; n[0]; ) {
        m = [];
        n.map( h => {
            [x,y,d] = h;
            D = i => [1,0,-1,0][d+i&3];
            p = v[h];
            for( j = 2; j--; ) {
                O = v[c = [X = x+D(j),Y = y+D(3-3*j),d+j&3]] ? 'K' : O;
                J = X|Y;
                J<0 || J>7 || I[Y][X] || v[c] ? O : (
                    m.push( c ),
                    v[c] = p + 'SR'[j]
                );
            }

            S = (x&y) > 6 ? p : S;
        } );
        n = m;
    }
    return S || O;
};
```

`v` is a hashtable with keys that are state triples `(x,y,d)` corresponding to (x,y) coordinate and direction of entry `d`. Each key has an associated value that is the string of `S` (straight) and `R` (turn right) moves required to reach the state represented by the key.

The code also maintains a stack of triples (in variable `n`) that have not been processed yet. The stack initially contains only the triple (0,0,0), corresponding to the state where the car faces right in the (0,0) cell. In the outer loop, `for( S = ... )`, the routine checks if any unprocessed triples remain. If so, it runs each unprocessed triple through the inner loop, `n.map( ...`.

The inner loop does five things:

1. computes the two possible moves (driving straight, turning right) out of the current state
2. if either of these moves leads to a state already registered in the hashtable, it is ignored for further processing. We flag the FALSE output as `K` (stuck), however, since we have found at least one loop where the car can continue to circle forever without crashing.
3. if a state is legal and novel, it is added to the hashtable (`v`) and to the stack of unprocessed triples (`m`) for the next pass of the outer loop
4. when the new state is registered in `v`, its value is set to the value of the originating state (the sequence of moves) plus `R` or `S` based on the current move
5. if `x` and `y` are `7`, the value of the originating state (the sequence of moves taken to reach the originating state) is copied to `S`, since this move sequence is a solution to the problem

After the inner loop terminates, `n` (the stack) is replaced by `m` (the new stack).

After the outer loop terminates (no new states were reached), the function returns its output. If the (7,7) cell was reached, `S` will contain a sequence of moves leading to this cell, and this is outputted. If the cell was not reached, `S` will be the empty string, and the routine falls through to outputting `O`, which will contain `K` (stuck) if and only if a loop was found, or `C` (crash) if the car will inevitably crash.

Comment: Got confirmation from OP, you can rename 'Crash' and 'Stuck' to 'C' and 'S'.

Comment: Ah. That saves a bit, then. Thanks. ;)

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing?  I can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: @phosgene: I've included a detailed explanation inline.

Comment: That's a clever procedure.  Nothing is wasted.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 339 - 10% = 305 bytes

I used a recursive depth-first search, which is terminated early on success via `exit`. Also printing path on success in the form of `00001010101010101010101110100111001000`, `0` for straight, `1` for right. The answer will be longer than optimal, since it is depth-first. I'm sure some optimizations to the algorithm could bring the byte count down quite a bit.

```
b=input()
D=[(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(0,1)]
def a(l):
 x,y=0,0
 v=2
 for d in l:
  if d=='1':v=(v+1) % 4
  x+=D[v][0]
  y+=D[v][1]
  if x<0 or x>7 or y<0 or y>7:return 0,x,y
  if b[y][x]:return -1,x,y
 return 1,x,y
def c(l):
 if len(l) < 39:
  t,x,y=a(l)
  if t==1:
   if (x,y)==(7,7):
    print l;exit(0)
   c(l+"0")
   c(l+"1")
c("")
print 0
```

Comment: Since this is Python 2, you can mix tabs and spaces for indents, like in `a`'s `for` loop. You also don't need spaces around operators, e.g. `(v+1) % 4` -> `(v+1)%4`. You can also join multiple statements onto one line by using `;` if there is no `if` or `for`, etc on the line, e.g `c(l+"0");c(l+"1")`. Some other golfs: `x,y,v=0,0,2`, `x|y>7 or x|y<0`, `x==y==7`. Good luck :)